# Can I modify Hive partition location using java api?

Tags: java, hive, partition

I am now developping system whose job is to consume data from kafka and put it into hive.Since the table have a partition "day" , so , the location of  this partition on hdfs will be `/root/tableLocation/day=20161110/adfadfaaf.avro` .

But, this location cannot meet my requirement.I want to change this location to  `/root/tableLocation/20161110/adfadfaaf.avro .`

The API I am using is apache hive metastore.Demo code when I create table is like this:

```
Table table = new Table(database, tableName);
table.setTableType(TableType.EXTERNAL_TABLE);
table.getParameters().put("EXTERNAL", "TRUE");
String tablePath = FileUtils.hiveDirectoryName(url, topicsDir, tableName);
table.setDataLocation(new Path(tablePath));
table.setSerializationLib(avroSerde);
try {
  table.setInputFormatClass(avroInputFormat);
  table.setOutputFormatClass(avroOutputFormat);
} catch (HiveException e) {
  throw new HiveMetaStoreException("Cannot find input/output format:", e);
}
List<FieldSchema> columns = HiveSchemaConverter.convertSchema(schema);
table.setFields(columns);
table.setPartCols(partitioner.partitionFields());
```

from the code , I can set the table location , 
but my question is , is there a way to set the partition location?

Comment: i think no as this this information should be part of Metadata ...

Answer (score 0):

in *hive* and *hdfs*, partitions are essentially sub directories under the table directory. The way *hive* recognizes a partition is by a structure such as,
`<col name>=<partition value>`
If you change that sub directory name to just `<partition value>`, it will not be recognized by hive as a partition.